# How to select multiple items in RecyclerView and put them into a List

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a list of `Objects` and those are populated in my `RecyclerView`, what I want to do is, I need to grab many of them to convert them into a `List`.

For example :

List of fruits : 
Green Apple
Pear
Orange
Cherry
Cherymoya
Kiwi

And then user wants to grab only the green ones, so he can select for example : Pear, Cherymoya, Green Apple.

So then I want all of those `Fruit` objects, create like a `List<Fruit>` and add them into it, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: share some code

Comment: please  share your code with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Boolean isSelected = false;` state variable to your fruit model, and mark it on view has been selected as `true`. Then you can see which fruits needs to be taken to list

Comment: But then how do I know when user wants to finish?

Comment: Depends on your UI, you can add a button or see it on some eventListener, or add event on exit button. On event just take items marked isSelected = true

Comment: I need to know how to do like adding a toolbar icon or something so I can tab and get the selected items, is that hard to do?

Comment: If it is not important just add button anywhere outside ViewHolder and thats it

Comment: Ok, I can do it, but how do I get the list when I click the button?

Comment: you have adapter, adapter has list. Just filter out items from that list which isSelected = true. It is hard to tell when there is no code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190379/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-antonis-radz).